# Как подружить JavaFX с Gradle в Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, gradle

Создал проект *JavaFX*, затем конвертировал его в проект *Gradle*. Пытаюсь собрать, но получаю *Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main*

Как подключить главный класс? Если создается проект на *Gradle*, то и в каталоге появляется файл `build.gradle`. В моем же случае ничего подобного не происходит. Как быть и как собрать? В программе всего один класс.

Вот код:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Media media = new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
        player.setAutoPlay(true);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,540,209);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Медиа плеер");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создай сам файл build.gradle в корне проекта.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

mainClassName = 'org.packagename.MyClass'

//version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Создал в корне проекта build.gradle, прописал путь к мейн классу (mainClassName = 'application.Main'). Все равно не находит его.

Comment: application это имя твоего пакета ?

Comment: Да, имя пакета, в котором находится класс Main

Comment: Посмотри данный туториал http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html